# Jquery CSS border

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I've made a small script that I use to alter the border of a div but it doesnt seem to work

This is my code

```
function changeBorderType(px, rr, gg, bb) {
        $("#colorBox").css({"border":  px+"px "+ getBorderType() +" rgb("+ rr +","+ gg +","+ bb +");"});
        console.log("border: " + px+"px "+ getBorderType() +" rgb("+ rr +","+ gg +","+ bb +");");
    }
```

Output that  Iam getting from the console.log is correct tho

> border: 1px solid rgb(231,212,164);

But on the page there are no effects at all, the border doesnt change or anything as such.

I also tried inspecting the element to see if there are any changes or so but it seems there aint no changes at all

EDIT:

Just to add up, this is my current CSS (default one)

```
#colorBox {
    width: 40%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(136,104,121);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? Are you sure you have that element in the DOM?

Comment: Here is a sample fiddle altho it says undefined $, but thats not the case on my own page, could be that I've pasted something wrongly there
https://jsfiddle.net/x1dtf4og/

Comment: Here is the update to your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1dtf4og/1/ You had the jQuery missing, you still had the semicolon (`;`) at the end, and you had an extra space in the `border ` key.

Comment: Yep that works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix, based on your jsfiddle:

```js
var pixelsSet = 5;
var red = 10;
var green = 122;
var blue = 155;

changeBorderType(pixelsSet, red, green, blue);

function changeBorderType(px, rr, gg, bb) {
  $("#box").css({"border":  px+"px " +" solid "+ "rgb("+ rr +","+ gg +","+ bb +")"});
  console.log("border: " + px+"px "+" solid "+" rgb("+ rr +","+ gg +","+ bb +")");
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">

</div>
```

> Problems solved:
>   1. There was an extra semicolor at the end of the border's value.
>   2. There was an extra space after the `border` key (it was `border`).

Comment: Thanks mate, god bless you and Merry Xmas to all!

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon (`;`) is not a valid css value. Which you have in your last value,

> 1px solid rgb(231,212,164);

So, your current code,

```
"border":  px+"px "+ getBorderType() +" rgb("+ rr +","+ gg +","+ bb +");"
```

Update it to,

```
"border":  px+"px "+ getBorderType() +" rgb("+ rr +","+ gg +","+ bb +")"
```

Sample,

```js
$(function() {
  var style1 = "1px solid rgb(231,212,164);";
  var style2 = "1px solid rgb(231,212,164)";

  $('#previousColorBox').css({
    'border': style1
  });

  $('#colorBox').css({
    'border': style2
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="previousColorBox">
  My Previous Color Box
</div>

<div id="colorBox">
  My Color Box
</div>
```

Comment: even without it, its still the same

Comment: @TomislavNikolic Judging from your edited question, you could actually just change only the `border-color`. Anyway, try to check my sample if it helps..